# What is the page size in UNIX?

Tags: unix

I have tried my best to understand the page translation concept shown [here](http://zoo.cs.yale.edu/classes/cs422/2010/lec/x86_translation.svg)

Offset is of 12 bits, it means there 4096 entries or 4K entries. And each entry in memory is of 32 bits or 4bytes. So it means that a page is of size 4K x 4Bytes = 16KB.

But that don't seems correct.

My calculations of size are messed up. Please help me understand this two level page translation with sizes.

According to given picture.
What is the size of frame?
What is the size of page?
What is the size of page table?

**Conclusion:**
So the answer I got from @chill is that in Page Directory and Page Table the size of offset is 32 bits and 1024 entries (hence 4KB) while in a page offset is of 8 bits and 4096 entries (hence 4KB)

Comment: I'm by no means an expert on the subject, but I'm pretty sure you're getting confused by what's being measured here. The size of each page table doesn't directly correlate to the size of each page. The page table having 4K entries means that it will be 16K in size on a 32-bit machine, because it has to store 4096 32-bit address pointers, each of which _points_ to a block in memory of fixed size (i.e. a page). The actual size of the page that each entry points to is not controlled by this. If it happens to be 4K, this means you can address 16MB of memory from that particular page table.

Comment: But if the offset is 12bits, it means that I can store maximum 4096 entries in page table?  So for 32 bit addresses maximum page size is 16KB? Is that correct?

Comment: No. See chill's comment on his answer. Each entry in a _page_ is just one byte, not four. This results in a 4KB page (12 bit index, 1 byte entry = 2^12 * 1 = 4096). The entries in a _page table_ are 4 bytes on a 32-bit machine each because they are pointers to pages. Since the page tables have a 10 bit index and 4 byte entries, the size of the page table is 2^10 * 4 = 4096 bytes.

Comment: Please don't close this question, I will include answer in question and send this to my fellows, it will help them understand this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Varies from machine to machine, can be obtained with `sysconf (_SC_PAGE_SIZE);`.

Comment: Sorry, I am learning page translation at student level and I need to know how it actually works. I have seen many links but they all just mess up.

Comment: @LifeH2O, On x86 each byte is 8 bits, not 32.

Comment: Yes, and 32 bits make 4bytes in total. What is the size of address to which page table points? I think it is of 32 bits, so it will make 4bytes

Comment: @LifeH2O, Page directory and each page table are indexed with 10 bits and have 4 byte entries, hence their size is 2^10 * 4 = 4KB. A page is indexed with 12 bits and have 1 byte entries (namely the bytes themselves :), hence page size is 2^12 * 1 = 4KB.

Comment: means I am wrong in saying that page has *32bit entries*, it actually has only *8bit entries* which are 4096 in number. 
.....
Would you please explain the PPN and offset? A PPN is of 20 bits, it means we can have 2^20 or 1M number of pages, and its offset can easily point to those 1Byte entries (which are 4906 in number) and each page is of size 4KB so it make 4GB total addressable space.
.....
It seems perfect now, please correct me if i concluded it wrong somewhere.

Comment: @LifeH2O, yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was 'stuck' on this topic and has not moved forward from many days